# jquery dialog not centering

Tags: c#, jquery, dialog

EDIT: rewrote this to be html only

In the following code, why is the jquery dialog that's displayed not centered? The dialog is opened by clicking the "test" button on the page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
  function showDialog() {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: {
            'Yes': function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return true;
            },
            'No': function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="width:800px; height:800px; border:solid 1px red;">

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic dialog"></div>

<input type="button" value="test" onclick="showDialog();"></input>

</div><!-- End demo -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not set the `position` option when you create the dialog?

Comment: @Matt Ball - I tried it, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I've definitely had some issues trying to position jQueryUI dialogs before. Any chance you can post a repro link (on jsbin or the like)?

Comment: @dcp - Try changing `"displayOkAlert();"` to `"$(displayOkAlert);"`, any effect?

Comment: @Nick Craver - Thanks, but it has no effect.

Comment: @Matt Ball - It's sort of a large app, not sure how easy it will be to isolate an example.

Comment: @Matt Ball - ok, I simplified my example above, you should be able to just past it in some folder where the jquery files are present and open the file in the browser to see the behavior.

Comment: You can try moving the dialog <div> outside (after) the primary div.

Comment: @orolo - doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding these includes:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.1.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your scenario at http://jsfiddle.net/zjRga/1/. I have tested it a few times and I cannot reproduce what you state. Can you double check it? Can you confirm us that you are not using any extra CSS?

**Note**: I have made some minor (non-crucial) changes to make it works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's something with the js files for jquery that are being included. You really need to try it standalone (i.e outside of a site like jsfiddle) so I can see what files are being included. JQuery seems to be extremely picky about this.